# Why Isnt js / jquery Events working in PHP foreach

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I understand foreach but this is new for me because within the foreach in PHP I have some script for each item that shows up and wondering why it only works for the item in the first item

In the code, I am getting an image from an MYSQL database. instead of using onclick in js I am learning more into jquery and only when I click the first image it will generate the
`$("#main").load("includes/product.php");` 
path and change I want to change but in the product name and the cart button do not change the visuals.

```
<section id="new-products" class="clearfix">
  <div class="title-block">
    <h4>New Products</h4>
  </div>
  <?PHP 
    foreach ($item as $items){
  ?>        
  <div class="left-col-block">
    <article class="product-box clearfix">   
    <a href="#store/category/<?PHP echo $items['category'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['brand'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['name'];?>" id="product-link">
      <img src="<?PHP echo $items['image']; ?>" alt="Card Games" title="Card Games" height="80" width="80">
    </a>
    <a href="#store/category/<?PHP echo $items['category'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['brand'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['name'];?>" id="product-link"><?PHP echo $items['name']; ?></a><br>
    <span class="price">$<?php echo $items['price'];?></span>
    <a href="#store/category/<?PHP echo $items['category'];?>/<?PHP echo $    ['brand'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['name'];?>" id="product-link" class="button tiny right icon-basket"></a>
   </article>
  `<script>
     $( "#product-link" ).click(function() {

     $("#main").load("includes/product.php");
     });
   </script>
 </div> 
 <div class="left-col-block">
 </div>
 <?PHP
 }
 ?>
</section>
```

Expected:
I am wanting each link with the id of product-link to give the event trigger with jquery on each product and each id

Actual Results:
`$("#main").load("includes/product.php");` 
only works on the first id that is equal to product-link

Comment: Because id of html element __must be unique__.

Comment: Maybe `$('.product-box a').click` where/what is the `#main`? I also wouldn't think you'd need 3 `a`s, you can put more content inside the one `a`.

Comment: Also you can move the `script` call outside the loop. It only needs to be defined once.

Comment: The a's the first one is a clickable image and the second one is the clickable name and the thirst is the cart icon and each one triggers the     $("#main").load("includes/product.php");  which changes the section to another file like the product.php it only has the code for when it changes

Comment: The #main is in the main php file and everything in it is right because i got the jquery .load work on the navbar and the footer stuff just having trouble with the items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer was
`<script>$( ".product-box a" ).click(function() {
 $("#main").load("includes/product.php");
 });</script>`
since product-bot was a class and I didn't realize the # makes it check for id and the. makes it search for a class and class is able to be called multiple times whereas an id has to be unique

Answer (score 0):

because of you have 3 like for each item and you want to set on click for every 3 link, you must use class attribute and set it unique for each item.

I changed your code to this:

```
<section id="new-products" class="clearfix">
    <div class="title-block">
        <h4>New Products</h4>
    </div>
    <?PHP
    foreach ($item as $key=>$items){
        ?>
        <div class="left-col-block">
            <article class="product-box clearfix">
                <a href="#store/category/<?PHP echo $items['category'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['brand'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['name'];?>" class="product-link-<?=$key?>">
                    <img src="<?PHP echo $items['image']; ?>" alt="Card Games" title="Card Games" height="80" width="80">
                </a>
                <a href="#store/category/<?PHP echo $items['category'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['brand'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['name'];?>" class="product-link-<?=$key?>"><?PHP echo $items['name']; ?></a><br>
                <span class="price">$<?php echo $items['price'];?></span>
                <a href="#store/category/<?PHP echo $items['category'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['brand'];?>/<?PHP echo $items['name'];?>" class="button tiny right icon-basket product-link-<?=$key?>"></a>
            </article>
            `<script>
                $( ".product-link-<?=$key?>" ).click(function() {

                    $("#main").load("includes/product.php");
                });
            </script>
        </div>
        <div class="left-col-block">
        </div>
        <?PHP
    }
    ?>
</section>
```